# Sending newline character in Javascript string

Tags: javascript

I want to send

```
var str = "Result1\nResult2";
```

`\n` servers as a separator.

However, this translates to

```
"Result1
Result2"
```

when sent. How can  I  get

```
"Result1\nResult2"
```

Comment: "Result1\\nResult2" didn't worked for you??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to catch it with RegEx, or something similar, that will still catch `\n` even if it displays as two lines. If you must have it as a literal, you can escape the backslash.

E.g.

`var str = "Result1\\nResult2";`

Here's a bit of a visual example using the RegEx search in Atom.

[image]

The highlighted part is the selection. As you can see, a new line character is selected when performing a RegEx search using `\n`, regardless of if it's actually shown as `\n`.

Answer (score 2):

Escape the backslash with another backslash.

```
var str = "Result1\\nResult2";
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings in many languages (including JavaScript), have a feature called escaping which allows you to embed certain blank characters for formatting and control purposes. The way you access them is with the backslash followed by a series of other characters (`"\n"` means newline, `"\t"` means tab, etc. Here's some info about JavaScript strings https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String). If you just want a backslash character you can use `"\\"` which is interpreted as a single backslash. If you wanted backslash followed by n you would have `"\\n"` — as many others have pointed out.

That being said, I wouldn't recommend you ever use `"\\n"` as a separator given that many programmers would see `"\n"` and immediately think newline. You could use the newline character itself `"\n"` as the separator (i.e., each item on its own line). Otherwise, if it is possible commas would probably be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

The backslash (\) is an escape character in Javascript as in other languages such as C.  This means that when Javascript encounters a backslash, it tries to escape the following character. For instance, \n is a newline character (rather than a backslash followed by the letter n).

In order to output a literal backslash, you need to escape it. Having said that, below is what you needs to do:

> var str="Result1\nResult2"